# How to properly access class functions from another class?

Tags: c++

So I made a two classes as such:

```
class Husky{
private: 
    int age;
    int weight;


public: 
    //Usual Constructor, set, get functions here
    //......
    void foo(); //<-----This is the problem function. In here, I change the weight variable.
}
```

And here is the second class:

```
class Dog{
private:
    vector<Husky> h;

public:
    Husky getHusky(int index);  //Returns the Husky element at the index given.
    void setHusky(Husky x){h.push_back(x);}  //Adds a Husky element to the 'h' array.
```

}

In my main:

```
int main(){

    //Note: the initialized value of `weight` is 0.

    Husky p;
    p.foo();
    cout << p.getWeight() << endl;  //This couts 5. foo() DID change 'weight'.


    Dog g;
    Husky s;
    g.push_back(s);

    g.getHusky(0).foo();

    cout << g.getHusky(0).getWeight() << endl;  //This couts 0. foo() DID NOT change 'weight'. 
    // Why did this not print out 5?
```

}

Give me a clue or something to point me in the right direction please.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know '&' can also be used like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dog::getHusky()` is returning a **copy** of the requested `Husky`, because you are returning it by value.  You are then calling `foo()` on the **copy** rather than on the **original**.  That is why you see the results you are seeing.

The solution is to change `getHusky()` to return the requested `Huskey` by reference instead of by value, eg:

```
Husky& getHusky(int index);
```

```
Husky& Dog::getHusky(int index) { return h[index]; }
```

Notice the `&` attached to the return type.